# Python 2.6: Opening 4GB file throws "IOError: [Errno 127] Value too large to be stored in data type" on AIX

Tags: python, python-2.6

When opening 4GB+ file on AIX Python 2.6.2 I receive IOError:

```
>>> fd = open('/mnt/t/MY_BIG_4GB_FILE', 'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 127] Value too large to be stored in data type: '/mnt/t/MY_BIG_4GB_FILE'
```

Any solutions? I didn't find information in Google.

**EDIT:**
To read BIG file I do something line that (I know that it is rubbish but sometimes You simply can't change python version):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["cat", source_file], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=BUFFER_SIZE)
try:
   for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
       # process line
       pass
finally:
   p.communicate()  # closing Popen
```

Comment: Is your OS 64-bit? If so, is your Python 64-bit?

Comment: The comment from @Tupteq is a solution. If I use /opt/freeware/bin/python2.7_64 instead of /opt/freeware/bin/python2.7 (fix the symlinks) on my AIX 7.2 then the problem dissappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for "large file support."  There is a decent brief here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/posix.html#large-file-support .  You likely need to recompile your Python interpreter with the appropriate options, or find a pre-built one that has those options.  Try a build of Python 2.7 if you can, while you're at it.